# Multi-level drop down menu in CSS not working properly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I am trying to spend time productively by playing with CSS and HTML. I have a menu with two levels where the second level is displayed on hover. And it works, but not the way I would like to. I have several problems with it:

- Second level menu is not adjacent to the first level of the menu.
- Second level menu items spread out the first level menu item they belong to and don't float to the right of it like they should.
- There is a margin of unknown origin to the left of the menu. You can see it if you look at the border.
- The style of the second item of the menu also affects the second child of the second level. Inline CSS solves that issue but is there a different better solution?

You can see the code on the following [page](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GDI10RGGTL47).
Can you point me my errors, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the position of the submenu, and prevent the size of the item at the main menu to change, you can do as follows:

give the **submenu** (ul element- can be what you declared as `.menu ul li ul`):

- `position:absolute`
- `padding:0` (the built-in padding of the ul element is what you called "margin of unknown origin")
- `left:100%` to set the submenu location.
- `top:0` to set the submenu location.

give it's **parent** (li element- can be what you declared as `.menu li`)):

- `position:relative`

As for the last issue, personally I think using "nth-child" for your case is not a good choise- I whould prefer using a dedicated class for active item.

But if you want to solve what you did here, just be more specific about what item you want to style:
instead of this selector: `.menu ul li:nth-child(2)`,
use this selector: `.menu > ul > li:nth-child(2)`.
so the style will be applied to the second direct `li` child of the main menu only.